# namespace pcl has no member named PointCloud in Point Cloud Library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, point-cloud-library

I am following the official [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/passthrough.php#passthrough) here to get started with the *Point Cloud Library*. But unfortunately I can get it working because I encountered the problem just from the very beginning, which says that namespace "pcl" has no member named PointCloud (in line 8 of the tutorial: `pcl::PointCloud<.....>`). The header files I used are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl-1.8/pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl-1.8/pcl/filters/passthrough.h>
#include <pcl-1.8/pcl/point_cloud.h>
```

I also added `$(PCL_ROOT)\include` and other `$(PCL_ROOT)\3rdParty` "include"s to `Project Properties\Configuration Properties\VC++ Directories\Include Directories\`,

besides that,

`$(PCL_ROOT)\lib` together with `$(PCL_ROOT)\3rdParty` "lib"s were also added to the `Project Properties\Configuration Properties\VC++ Directories\Library Directories`.

Further I added relevant libs to `Project Properties\Configuration Properties\Linker\Input\Additional Dependencies`, namely, `pcl_common_debug.lib` and `pcl_filters_debug.lib`.

`$(PCL_ROOT)` is the path to where the PCL installed and has already been added to the environment. The platform was set to x64 in debug mode. I was using the latest version of PCL, i.e. PCL-1.8.1-AllInOne-msvc2015-win64 on VS 2015 (64bit) on a windows 10 pro machine.

I googled the problem but still can't figure out what was wrong. Did I set up anything improperly? I very appreciate any help from you! Thank you so much.

The error I got is shown below:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Yev.jpg)

Comment: My bet is that it is not the first error shown in output window... Btw post the error verbatim

Comment: Hi @Rama, thank you for your comment. I uploaded a snapshot of the error. Would you mind taking a look at it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`pcl::PointCloud` is defined in the `pcl/point_cloud.h` header. Assuming `$(PCL_ROOT)` is the actual instalation folder, you are incorrectly adding `pcl-1.8` to your include statements. It is normally invoked simply as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/passthrough.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add these lines into cmakelists, I have solved the problem by this.

```
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```